# Telerik report kendo UI angular toolbar icon not loading proper

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, telerik-reporting

[image]

toolbar icons are not loading  In index.html

```
<link href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2020.3.1118/styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2020.3.1118/styles/kendo.blueopal.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
```

used this and     "@progress/telerik-angular-report-viewer": "^15.22.119" and angular 10.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Looks connected to icon fonts. If there are no console errors, you can read the articles below and use FontAwesome template.

```
templateUrl: "/Scripts/telerikReportViewerTemplate-FA-yourversion.html",
```

[Manual Setup](https://docs.telerik.com/reporting/using-reports-in-applications/display-reports-in-applications/web-application/html5-report-viewer/manual-setup)
[Html5 Report Viewer toolbar icons not rendered in IE browser](https://docs.telerik.com/reporting/knowledge-base/html5-viewer-toolbar-icons-not-shown-in-ie-browser)

Comment: In chrome also not loading